# Batch segmentation with Age not working in cdp personalize

Tags: cdp

I am facing a issue while creating a batch segment using Age filter for users of type Customer.

The **Date of Birth** in the user profile is there as:

`"dateOfBirth": "1989-12-04T00:00:00.000Z",`

The batch segment is unable to calculate the age. I am using the Partner SandBox.

Please can someone tell me, `why the batch segment with age filter is failing?`

Every time it shows three user only no latest user based on age are updated in the segment.

Comment: batch segments are daily re-calculated. Are you observing this after 24h?

Answer (score 0):

Age is not an out of the box field in Sitecore CDP and Personalize. If Age is appearing when you are creating a Batch Segment this means that Age has been added as a data extension in this tenant. In this case Age is being ingested into the platform using Batch Import or our REST APIs. Age is not being calculated automatically using Date of Brith.